# Customize Title in Charts DevExtreme

Tags: javascript, devextreme

How can I customize title to the valueAxis like this:

```
        argumentAxis: {
               label: {
                   customizeText: function () {
                       return this.value + '';
                   }
               },
```

This example is happening with the lable. Could I use the same function  to the title of valueAxis and title of chart?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExtreme Charts don't have any callback functions for title of a chart or title for axes.

There are many labels for axes so they can depends on some values or arguments of axis and callback function is really helpful in this case. But title is a single static element, so it would be simplest to set it like a string in settings object:

```
//...
title: {
   text: "Title of chart"
},
argumentAxis: {
   title: {
      text: "Title of argument axis"
   }
},
valueAxis: {
   title: {
      text: "Title of value axis"
   }
}
//...
```

I hope it will be useful for you. Thanks!

Comment: Can we work dynamically these elements? I'd like to change every time that I have a different result  on database. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can change those title with this code: $("#chartContainer").dxChart("instance").option("argumentAxis.title", "new title");